# How to change color of button with javascript/jquery when input (radio buttons) is selected

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>
 <button id="id1" class="button">button1</button>
 <button id="id2" class="button">button2</button>
 <button id="id3" class="button">button3</button>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId1">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"  value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"  value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"  value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId2">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2"  value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2"  value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2"  value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId3">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3"  value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3"  value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3"  value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
```

If input with id `id1` is selected in form with id `formId1` then color of button with id `id1` should be change and If input with id `id2` is selected in form with id `formId2` then color of button with id `id2` should be change and same for third button also.

Comment: Can you please indicate anything you've tried.  If you haven't tried anything, what have you researched.

Comment: An Id attribute should always be unique. There are several elements in your code with same id. Take care of that.

Comment: In the future, if asking for a javascript/jquery solution, you should post the javascript/jquery you've tried. Questions are better suited towards "why isn't this working" or "what am i doing wrong" or "ive tried this". When given just the HTML, it seems like you want SO to write code for you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @vapurrmaid Thank you, I will remember that so i don't do same mistake again in future

Answer (score 1):

You can call function on click to set the button color,

```
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"  onclick="handleClick('id1')"  value="male"> Male<br>
```

In this code we have added `onclick="handleClick('id1')"`

```js
handleClick =function(id){

// uncomment if you want to reset other button
/*
for(var i=1 ;i<4;i++){
     var button = document.getElementById("id"+i);
      button.style.backgroundColor = "buttonface";
}*/
     var property = document.getElementById(id);
      property.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
```

```html
<div>
 <button id="id1" class="button">button1</button>
 <button id="id2" class="button">button2</button>
 <button id="id3" class="button">button3</button>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId1">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"  onclick="handleClick('id1')"  value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"onclick="handleClick('id1')"   value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id1"onclick="handleClick('id1')"  value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId2">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2" onclick="handleClick('id2')"   value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2"  onclick="handleClick('id2')"  value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id2" onclick="handleClick('id2')"   value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="" id="formId3">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3" onclick="handleClick('id3')"   value="male"> Male<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3" onclick="handleClick('id3')"   value="male"> female<br> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="id3" onclick="handleClick('id3')"   value="male"> others<br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are always welcome @chiragprajapati, If your problem solved and you find this helpful, accept the answer and vote so that others can find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
     <button id="id1" class="button">button1</button>
     <button id="id2" class="button">button2</button>
     <button id="id3" class="button">button3</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="" id="formId1">
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onchange="setColor('id1')"> Male</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onchange="setColor('id1')"> female</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onchange="setColor('id1')"> others</label><br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="" id="formId2">
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" onchange="setColor('id2')"> Male</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" onchange="setColor('id2')"> female</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onchange="setColor('id2')"> others</label><br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="" id="formId3">
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" onchange="setColor('id3')"> Male</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" onchange="setColor('id3')"> female</label><br> 
       <label><input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" onchange="setColor('id3')"> others</label><br>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      function setColor(target){
      
        document.getElementById(target).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
      
    </script>
```

Comment: You are always welcome. If your problem solved.. Mark the answer.